# DialogResult Infinite Loop

Tags: while-loop, switch-statement, infinite-loop, dialogresult

So I have this project at school to create a game "Guess the number". I am trying to loop a DialogResult using a switch statement and a while loop. I tried many possibilities but I go into a infinite loop. Just to know I am a beginner.I would really need some help here if possible. This is my code. Thanks in advance.

```
private void btnStartTheGame_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int guessTheNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberGuess.Text);
            DialogResult dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Is number" + number.ToString() + " you are thinking about?", "Answer the question!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
            switch(dialogResult)
            {
```

`case DialogResult.No:
                    while (dialogResult == DialogResult.No)
                    {
                        Random newNumberGenerator = new Random();
                        number = newNumberGenerator.Next(0, 101);
                        MessageBox.Show("Is number" + number.ToString() + " you are thinking about?", "Answer the question!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);

                    }
                    break;
            case DialogResult.Yes:
                    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Yes)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Congratulation! You guessed the number!!");
                        break;
                    }
                    break;                                                              
        }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to load the new result of the dialog.

```
int guessTheNumber = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberGuess.Text);
DialogResult dialogResult;
do
{
    Random newNumberGenerator = new Random();
    number = newNumberGenerator.Next(0, 101);
    dialogResult = MessageBox.Show("Is number" + number.ToString() + " you are thinking about?", "Answer the question!", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
} while (dialogResult == DialogResult.No);

MessageBox.Show("Congratulation! You guessed the number!!");
```

The `do` loop will execute the code first, and then check the condition. THis will also prevent having the same piece of code at different places, meaning the same.

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked like a charm!